# AWS s3 listing does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am running into below issue while I am trying to list files using aws s3 ls command. Any suggestions?

```
server:~/bin> aws s3 ls

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x2531450>, 'Connection to s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

Does this have anything to do with security groups? Unfortunately I am not able to post verbose output, stackoverflow doesnt allow me to do so..

Comment: can you confirm you can connect to amazon web site through port 443 `nc -vz s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com 443` ? you can also run the command with debug mode `aws s3 ls --debug` to get more information about when the error happens

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I have 2 servers, from first the aws s3 ls works and in the second I see the error. But nc -vz s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com 443 is failing in both servers with the error : nc: connect to s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out

Comment: from your second server, do you have outbound traffic allowed on port 80 and 443 ?

Comment: @BJC Were you able to figure it out. I am facing the same issue and haven't been able to solve it for past 2 days

Comment: @CaptainHere I vaguely remember I think I had solved by setting a http_proxy and https_proxy

Answer (score 3):

Try to use below command

aws s3 --region us-west-2 ls

Also, check AWS credentials should be there in your /root/.aws/credentials file.

Also check whether you have permission to access S3 from that instance or not.